# Initialize C++ struct

Tags: c++, winapi, struct, initialization

```
struct CUSTIOMSTRUCT
{
    FLOAT x, y, z;
    DWORD color;
};

CUSTOMSTRUCT MyVertex = {320.0f, 50.0f, 1.0f, 0xFF00FFCC};
```

I don't understand that part:

```
{320.0f, 50.0f, 1.0f, 0xFF00FFCC};
```

I have to put them in order?

Sorry but I'm C# guy.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/designators.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to put them in order. C99 version of C language offers "tagged" aggregate initializers, which allows one to "put them" out of order, but it is not in C++ (yet?).

Comment: Is it ever likely to be in C++ since we have constructors?

Comment: This isn't in the upcoming C++ standard, either.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they have to be in the order of declaration, so {x, y, z, color}.

Answer (score -5):

To be more precise,

{ } operator returns a few memory bytes,
So when u use

{320f , 50f, 1f, 0xFF00FFCC}
It returns a continues 16 bytes of memory that is then copied via "memcpy" command to the struct variable.

So if you put these out of order, the program compiles fine but doesnt work fine.

The better options would be to use constructors.

Comment: -1, This is misleading. There is no operator {} in the C++ language, that syntax in that context is an *initializer clause*. Even assuming that you are referring to that by other name, the behavior that you are depicting differs from what the *initializer clause* does. As an example, if the initializer clause was just `{ 320f }`, it would still initialize the rest of the struct to 0, being equivalent to `{ 320f, 0f, 0f, 0 }` i.e. the effect of the brace initializer depends as much on the object being initialized as on the contents of the brace itself. No `memcpy` is ever called in the process.

Comment: David, you're totally wrong. First of all, an operator is not neccessarily a compile time operator (as you should already know), second, the example you provided totally proves my theory! You can use memcpy with less than enough data. Third, no memcpy is called since this is a compile time operation, but for a C# guy this was the best explanation possible.